# Noob JavaScript error (Can't set property 'src' of null)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple error with my javascript file (Can't set property 'src' of null)

I am trying to change the image once in 1 second.

Here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>

    </head>
<body >
<div class='bannerbg'>
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class='slider'></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
images=new Array
(
"img/1.jpg",
"img/2.jpg",
"img/3.jpg"
);  


function left() //this function change the index of the array of images
{
    images.push(images.shift());

}

function change(){

    i=document.querySelector("#bannerbg img");

    i.src=images[0];
}

setInterval("left(); change()",1000);
```

Comment: You aren't using jQuery.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are using class bannerbg but your query is looking for ID bannerbg

Comment: @Pavlo: Actually, while it's not recommended, [you can.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector(".bannerbg img");
```

Your `div` has "bannerimg" as class, so you'll need to ude a period to tell the `querySelector` to look for a class.

The `#` is used to look for `id` properties, like this:

```
<div id='bannerbg'>
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class='slider'></div>
</div>
```

However, for maximum compatibility, I'd suggest adding a id to the image element:

```
<img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" id="myImage">
```

Then you can use [`document.getElementById("myImage")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) to access the specific element.
`getElementById` is one of the better supported DOM access functions, it will even work on IE versions as old as 5.5.

---

On a different note:

Your `setInterval` call is a bit of a [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Syntax). (See the explanation at the "code" parameter)

A better option would be to call it like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    left();
    change();
},
1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector comes up empty and thus the following attempt to set `src` fails.

---

In this line

```
<div class='bannerbg'>
```

you actually declare a `class` to that `<div>` and not an id. Within the selector, however, you use a `#`, which refers to ids. So either change the selector to use `.` as a class selector

```
i=document.querySelector(".bannerbg img");
```

or change your HTML to set an `id` instead of a `class`

```
<div id='bannerbg'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey your using the id selector not a class selector # = id . = class. This means you dont select any element hence the error.

Try

```
document.querySelector(".bannerbg img");
```